# Variables changing value automatically without any link in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have two variables in my controllers in AngularJS i.e

```
_this.currentData=new Array();
_this.masterCurrentData=new Array();
```

Later I created another temporary Array of Objects and filled separately using loops etc.

```
var tmpDataSort=[{
    "values":new Array(),
             disabled: false,
            "key":"Retail"
        },{
            "values":new Array(),
             disabled: true,
            "key":"Commercial"
        },{
            "values":new Array(),
             disabled: true,
            "key":"Industrial"
        },{
            "values":new Array(),
             disabled: true,
            "key":"Residential"
        }]
_this.masterCurrentData=tmpDataSort;
_this.currentData=tmpDataSort;
tmpDataSort=null;
```

Later whenever I am performing an operation on Current Data automatically the value of MasterCurrentData is changing and I have never used masterCurrent Data

```
_this.modifyCurrentBean = function(locName, selectFlag){
    console.log(_this.masterCurrentData[0].values)
        for(var i=0;i<_this.currentData.length;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<_this.currentData[i].values.length;j++){
                if(_this.currentData[i].values[j].x==locName){                      
                    _this.currentData[i].values.splice(j,1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(_this.masterCurrentData[0].values)
    }
```

The first console shows [object object]
and the second console show only an single [object]

Comment: Can you make a demo, so we could try something to help you.

Comment: Well since currentData and masterCurrentData refer to the same array. Calling splice on the array will affect both.

Comment: `currentData` and `masterCurrentData` point at the same array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign `tmpDataSort` to `_this.currentData` and `_this.masterCurrentData`, so by changing `_this.currentData` you change `tmpDataSort` and `_this.masterCurrentData` as well. You can make a copy of `tmpDataSort` using `_this.currentData=angular.copy(tmpDataSort);`